# change left value after css animation has finished

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to run a animation of a div sliding into veiw and another div sliding out of veiw but i think what happens is the code runs too quick and sets the display to none so you cannot see the animation happen is there anyway i can run the animation first then set the display and left value?

```
<script>
    var pagenumon = '1';
    function slide(pagenum){

        var whichpage = 'page' + pagenum;
        var waspage = 'page' + pagenumon;
        if(pagenum > pagenumon){
        document.getElementById(waspage).style.WebkitAnimation = "transition-left-out 0.5s";
        document.getElementById(waspage).style.animation = "transition-left-out 0.5s";
        document.getElementById(whichpage).style.WebkitAnimation = "transition-left-in 0.5s"; // Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
        document.getElementById(whichpage).style.animation = "transition-left-in 0.5s";
        }else{
        document.getElementById(waspage).style.WebkitAnimation = "transition-right-out 0.5s";
        document.getElementById(waspage).style.animation = "transition-right-out 0.5s";
        document.getElementById(whichpage).style.WebkitAnimation = "transition-right-in 0.5s"; // Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
        document.getElementById(whichpage).style.animation = "transition-right-in 0.5s";
        }
        if(pagenum == '1'){
            document.getElementById('page1').style.left = '0%';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'none';
        }else{
        if(pagenum == '2'){
            document.getElementById('page1').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.left = '0%';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'none';
        }else{
        if(pagenum == '3'){
            document.getElementById('page1').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.left = '0%';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            if(pagenum == '4'){
            document.getElementById('page1').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.left = '0%';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            if(pagenum == '5'){
            document.getElementById('page1').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.left = '0%';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.left = '100%';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            if(pagenum == '6'){
            document.getElementById('page1').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.left = '-100%';
            document.getElementById('page5').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.left = '0%';
            document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'block';

        }}}}}}
                window.pagenumon = pagenum;}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not see the animation because it's not possible to animate `display`. So what you should do is:

- Make sure you have `overflow: hidden` so no extra scroll would appear
- Perform the animation by setting the `left` to `100%` or whatever
- Delay `display:none` being applied

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('page6').style.display = 'none';
}, 500)
```

- And you definitely need to refactor the code, hiding stuff is definitely a separate function, you should hide non-active pages in some kind of loop, not by repeating that in the code.

Comment: what should i have overflow hidden on, the page layout is just body -> page1 page2 ect they are only contained by the body

Comment: @user1899614 You're moving a div to `left: 100%`, but it still has width and is visible. Just try and you'll see.